# jQuery Autocompletion with Eclipse Juno Java EE

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, aptana

I've read several DATED information on how to enable jQuery (specially auto completion) support for Eclipse. Either using Aptana or other plugins.

I've tried Aptana 3 version plugin, but I get nothing but problems.

Can someone please explain on how to achieve this?

Maybe nowadays there are better options from Aptana.

Tried with Eclipse Indigo and Helios, and still Aptana Web tools pkg. does not work.

Comment: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery

Comment: actually ignore that link, it does afaik nothing what-so-ever. intellij gets jquery support out of th ebox :-(

Comment: did you ever find a decent solution for this ?

Comment: lol, I thought about it. Maybe I should too ...

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this would be but this looks promising <http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/wiki/Installation>

Comment: this link is broken https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/wikis/Installation> Use this link https://code.google.com/archive/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I got the jQuery code completion in Juno. Just follow the following steps:

1) Install the [JSDT jQuery Integration plugin](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/jsdt-jquery/)

[image]

---

2) Go to Project Explorer--> JavaScript Resources

[image]

---

3) Right click on it and go to properties.

---

4) Select "Add JavaScript library"

[image]

---

5) Select  "jQuery Library"

[image]

---

6) You will get code completion as follows

[image]

Enjoy.

Comment: Has anyone had this problem: `$().` brings up the autocomplete list but `jQuery().` does not. It should work for both. I've even tried adding the library with the "no conflict" option checked and in this case, neither methods work.

Comment: @Mandar Deshpande Thanks it worked bro. Can you tell if I want a code assist for backone.js, Is that there eclipse????

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: As the Backbone.js is released just 3 years ago and it is not that much popular, eclipse has not released the auto-complete feature for that till now. I will provide a update here as soon as i get to know about that feature.

Comment: The link to JSDT jQuery is 404 now.

Answer (score 11):

Much simpler thanks to [logic8 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731884/jquery-autocompletion-with-eclipse-juno-java-ee#comment-26821787) is to add it from

`help > Install new software`

and enter `http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/updatesite`

Tada!!

Answer (score 1):

I have used https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angularjs-eclipse 
Once you install this you can right click on your project , Configure to Angularjs project ,

And that's it.

Comment: That is nothing about jQuery??

Answer (score 0):

There is just something I have not seen anyone say.

If you already have a ready project, but when you created it did not using a javascript project, then you must convert your existing project.

Keep calm, because this conversion will not harm your existing project.

> `Right click on your project` > `Configure` > `Convert to javascript project`

Ready! Now you can follow the step by step our friend up here did.

I believe this can really help beginners like me.