# eclipse - how to extend the build-in javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

While modifing my eclipse juno 4.2 with some WebDev-Features, I am currently stuck while adding library support for JQuery, JQMobi and other.

This is my situation:

[image: Situation]
<sub>(source: [codespot.com](https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/jsdt-jquery/wiki/images/add-javascript-library.png))</sub>

This would be my goal:

[image: Goal]

---

**The Problem**

Is it only possible to manipulate the build-in JS-Libraries of Eclipse through plugins or manually too?

Because, when I click on `Add JavaScript library`, I don't get this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezptb.png]

In my case, there is only `User Library` - how can I add other ones?!

These links were kind of helpful, but don't show a solution to my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892508/1370465

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-jsdt/

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery#.UVB0clfAm2U

Answer (score 0):

A user library represent sets of JavaScript files chosen by a user and preset through the User Libraries preference page.

[image: User Libraries preference page (Juno SR2)]

Everything else is provided by plug-ins.