# JSDT partial jQuery code assist in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jsdt

I've just figured out how to enable jQuery code assist in Eclipse (Kepler), partly thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731884/jquery-autocompletion-with-eclipse-juno-java-ee) post. 
So yeah I've got code assist on some of the API, but not on things like $.ajax(), or $.parseJSON(). Code assist for $('#id') does provide the expected functions like bind() and on(). $. just provide apply() and call(), which are only some of the JS function methods. It also seems to matter where in code I call on $, yielding different results in different places.

What could be the reason for this? I'd love to have code assist for the $ methods.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of tern.java.

I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) and you activate [jQuery support](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support). You will benefit with the whole case that you wish to have :

[image: $.ajax]