# Building a desktop application in UI5 environment using HTML5 elements

Tags: html, sapui5

I am beginner in sapui5. My requirement is to build a Desktop application in SAPUI5 environment using HTML5 elements. What IDE can I use to build that. Please refer me some links which help me in that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First get Eclipse Juno... then-

Go to Help > Install New Software
[image: Go to Help > Install New Software]

Select SAP Development Tools For Eclpse Juno 
[image: Select SAP Development Tools For Eclpse Juno]

Install.

All the best...

Answer (score 1):

I´d recommend you to use [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/keplersr2) since it supports SAPUI5 very well.

To get the SAPUI5 Tools available in your Eclipse IDE you can follow the [UI5 Setup guide](https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#sapui5).

In addition I´d recommend you to setup auto completion for SAPUI5. This is described [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/CodeCompletion.html).

If you like to have jQuery auto completion as well you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892508/1969374).

**UPDATE:**

If you prefer to develop with Sublime Text you can have a look at [SublimeUI5](https://github.com/qmacro/SublimeUI5), too.