# Get suggestion of jquery methods in eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse

I started learning jQuery.
I have downloaded and added development version in my project.
I am not able to get suggestion for different methods available for a particular tag or element.

> I want that if i select something and type method "slide",eclipse
>   should provide me slideUp,slideDown and slideToggle() etc.

What i am missing here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731884/jquery-autocompletion-with-eclipse-juno-java-ee