# Completion of jQuery or object in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse JavaScript Editor: content assist for js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006934/eclipse-javascript-editor-content-assist-for-js-files)

I used eclipse to write code in javascript.

Is it possible that the eclipse will complete word or statement in jQuery or in javascript?

For example

```
$("test").
```

then I want to get the option of all the functions or

```
var obj = { key : 1 , val : 2 }
```

when I press obj. I want to get key or val

Is it possible to do it in eclipse ?

Comment: apparently it is possible, but I tired regularly to get it to work using a vareity of plugins and or settings. It never did. Use netbeans, or intellij and it works straight away with no fussing. They also have many other benefits.

Comment: what is netbeans or intellij  ? does they plugin to eclipse ?

Comment: they are like eclipse, but better.  Speaking as someone with 10yrs experience of eclipse who recently switched. They are IDE's just google them.

Comment: I found them , If I will download them then the eclipse should be updated ?

Comment: they are completely separate from eclipse. You need to understand what an IDE is.

Comment: Hi I need that it will work on eclipse and not outside from eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [**Aptana Studio** plugin for eclipse](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download). Its code assist capabilities work out of the box for vanilla JavaScript, and can be extended quite easily to supports common JavaScript libraries as well (e.g. jQuery).