# javascript - hint on methods/fields when pressing the dot

Tags: javascript, eclipse, api, bing-maps

I'm trying to learn javascript with bing maps.

How can I type dot (.) and see what the API has to offer? I don't want to go to the MSDN every time I'm looking for a method. Example:

```
mapTypeId:Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
```

except road (at the end), there are other options such as: birdseye, collinsBart etc.
I know this because I had to read the [MapTypeId Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427625.aspx). It would have been easier if I could only click the dot after the MapTypeId and get the enumeration.

Is there a way to do this? (I'm using eclipse).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006934/eclipse-javascript-editor-content-assist-for-js-files

Comment: Note sure if Eclipse take into consideration JS-libraries that you reference. Otherwise I guess you can use the developer tools of your browser to get that kind of autocompletion (works with Chrome atleast), if you go to the page where you have referenced the library and open up the console.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can use the VEJS project managed by the community.
In the source code, you'll find a Microsoft.Maps-vsdoc.js that you can add in reference into your project.

See: http://vejs.codeplex.com/

And example here: http://vejs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69631#1162331 

Don't know how it could work in Eclipse still.

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps v7 SDK now has intellisense for Visual Studio. You can find out all about it here: http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/09/04/the-art-of-intellisense-three-ways-to-use-intellisense-with-bing-maps-apis/