# How to enable code assist for the DOM for JavaScript projects in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-completion

How can I simply get in this little popup (code completion) all possible methods/functions given when I type window.(blablabla).
Because if I type window. there is no "event" method for example.

In NuSphere there are all methods been listed.

Comment: I have already installed all possible plug-ins and have read most of the internet content...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1006934/360705

Answer (score 2):

Please differentiate between JavaScript and DOM code assist. There are many questions/answers here about this but it's ambiguous which of these two they refer to. None, I've seen, particularly claims to have found a solution for **DOM** and most mentions Aptana as standalone IDE or Eclipse plugin for solution.

For reasons outside the scope of this question I use **Eclipse Indigo** (3.7.2) and got this working w/o Aptana. This solution probably depends on the JavaScript Development Tools plugin.

First in the Navigator pane right click the project and hover the *Configure* option. Select *Convert to JavaScript project* or *Add JavaScript Support*.

Open project properties and a JavaScript item should appear in the left hand side list of configuration options. Expand and select *Include Path*. In the Libraries tab on the right you will see *ECMA Script* and *ECMA 3 Browser Support*. Switch to the *Global Supertype* tab and tick the *ECAM 3 Browser Support* checkbox. Restart Eclipse.

--

However in my case this last option didn't seem to work (when selected 'window' as global supertype, below the list got 'Window() null') and window. didn't bring results but document. and all other JS globals did. (So I could say for e.g. `var w = document.defaultVeiw;` and w. did bring up desired list.)

Comment: sorry, but no effect. Its not possible to convert because I simple does not have the option

Comment: Do you have JavaScript Development Tools plugin installed as write above that's required for this? Or maybe this is provided by an other JS related plugin, I'm not sure. First try with JDT and of not, I can try and find out which plugin provides this feature.

Comment: Anything installed. Nothing works. I have Eclipse Juno, because under other versions I get NullPointerExceptions and Overflows, don't ask me why