# KendoUI with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, kendo-ui

I want to use the jsp wrapper for KendoUI with NetBeans.

In my controller I added the example code for ComboBox:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("fabrics", new DropDownListItem[] {
            new DropDownListItem("Cotton", "1"),
            new DropDownListItem("Polyester", "2"),
            new DropDownListItem("Cotton/Polyester", "3"),
            new DropDownListItem("Rib Knit", "4")
    });

    model.addAttribute("sizes", new String[] {
        "X-Small",
        "Small",
        "Medium",
        "Large",
        "X-Large",
        "2X-Large"
    });

    return "web/combobox/index";
}
```

I do an import:

```
import com.kendoui.spring.models.DropDownListItem;
```

But NetBeans says: **package import com.kendoui.spring.models does not exist**.
I added the dependency for kendo-taglib-2013.1.319.jar to pom.xml by using the "Manually install artifact" feature of NetBeans. When using KendoUI on html side everything works fine.

The requirements found on http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/jsp/introduction say that "Eclipse Juno for Enterprise Developers (J2EE support)" is required.

Have you guys ever successfully used KendoUI with NetBeans? When yes, what are the steps to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: you can use kendo ui in netbeans but at your own. there is no special integration. check up netbeans latest amazing version 7.4 . It includes building by cordova to android and ios packages. you can start a kendo ui project as an html5 cordova application. I hope this helps.

take a look into the following answers:

1. [there no company supported IDE for Kendo UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091911/is-there-a-gui-designer-for-kendo)
2. [Eclipse not fully supported](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/general-discussions/eclipse-ide-setup-for-code-completion-checking.aspx)
3. [Eclipse trying to assist you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006934/eclipse-javascript-editor-content-assist-for-js-files-autocompletion)
4. [Kendo UI Bootstrapper (Helper to start up your project)](http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-07-23/bootstrapper-intro.aspx)

I hope this helps. And if anyone is capable of developing `Kendo Ui` with `NetNeans` I will thank him a lot