# Is there a GUI designer for Kendo?

Tags: ide, kendo-ui

Does Kendo have anything for designing placement of controls like Sencha Architect for Ext JS?

Not just an IDE like WebStorm that makes typing the JavaScript easy, but one that does drag & drop for laying out controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. But this is definitely in our long-term plans and we are working in this direction.

Comment: Any idea when? thanks - dave

Comment: Was wondering the same thing - a tool like [Polymer Designer](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/).

Comment: Still not there in 2016 I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Found this today, looks promising but is not free.

https://www.progress.com/openedge/components/kendo-ui-builder