# jquery, dojo, XSP javascript Code Assist for Domino Designer 8.5.3

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

While working with XPages i need more and more ClientSide javascript libraries, like dojo, jquery and kinetic.js. But when working with all these libs i miss the Code Assist especially when working with new libraries.

I found some solutions how to get jquery/dojo Code Assist to work in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/using_javascript_content_assist.htm) but i cant get it to work in Domino Designer.

I also tried to install the [Aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006934/eclipse-javascript-editor-content-assist-for-js-files-autocompletion) plugin into my Designer but that was just a mess of warnings and error messages.

**Update:** Tried aptana ecplipse plugin for [Eclipse 3.4](http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.4/023903/index.html). After i got the feeling that i clicked tousend times "yes install this plugin" and about an hour later when notes was finished with restarting i could start the aptana/designer.

At first i saw no change when opening a js file but after changing the default editor in 
Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations (or opening the files with right click open with...) i was able to use the aptana js editor and on the first look i got what i wanted but i think i have to experiment a bit i cant say what effects that will have on the whole Notes.

If there is no other solution i have at least this editor to support me when writing js scirpts in the xpage editor i will still have to know what dojo.xY i have to use.

Comment: Which version of Designer are you using? Please be aware that the Designer is based on an older version of Eclipse and is also heavilly customized. I think that version 9 of designer is based on eclipse 3.4 or maybe 3.5 but I dont show for sure.

Comment: Yes, i know that Designer !== Eclipse but i hoped there is still a way wich works in both. (under all those customizations there maby could be at least somithing usefull) Does designer 9 supports code Assistent for javascript libraries ?

Comment: Designer 9 is still based on Eclipse 3.4. This is because it uses Expeditor as a middle layer, which still has 3.4 dependencies. Expeditor is also used by the Notes client and Sametime. As a result, the Designer team can't switch to a newer version of Eclipse (currently, the newest is 4.3) until they get permission to do so from the Notes and Sametime teams. Strange to think that improving Designer could break Sametime, but it's true. At least they don't also have to negotiate with the Symphony people anymore.

Comment: An older Version of Aptana might work. Look for one that runs with Eclipse 3.4

Comment: @stwissel already on it. I'll Update my question when i got a result.