# Missing Element attributes of javascript in eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

When I create a source javascript file and start to code, I find that eclipse does not have full support for the javascript library(code hint). For example, I use `document.getElementById(id).`

Then I press Ctrl + Space, no hint of any attribute for this element, only the function hint. It may be missing some attribute such as innerHTML or style.

Comment: it is not quite clear what you are asking precisely. It would help if you could point out your question in bold.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse JavaScript Editor: content assist for js files, autocompletion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006934/eclipse-javascript-editor-content-assist-for-js-files-autocompletion)